# Microsoft visual studio doesn't show any android emulator or physical device for Xamarin project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I have a xamarin project and i want to debug it, but visual studio doesn't show any emulator or physical device.
this is the menu

[image: devices list]

I wanted to restart adb from tools > android but it's disabled. but when I open a non xamarin project (for example a web porject) this options is enabled.

[image: adb restart is disabled]

I can see my device in cmd with command `adb devices` and in android studio, every thing is fine and I can deploy some java application to my phone.
do you have Any idea?

**Update**

I created new project and in this new project, every thing is fine and I can debug with my phone or emulators.
but in my existing project which I'm currently working on, there is no device in list.

Comment: Is usb debugging enabled in your android developers settings? If yes, when you reconnect the phone, you'll get a notification where you should click "yes"

Comment: usb debugging is enabled and as I said, i can use my phone for debugging in android studio.
but it's not listed in visual studio

Comment: @ahmadeqbal Is the Xamarin.Android set to be the active|current project?

Comment: Yes, it is set as startup project

Comment: @ahmadeqbal 's comment helped me. If anyone is wondering how to make it so, just right click on `App.Android` in your Solution explorer and choose `Set as StartUp Project`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It happened to me just now using vs 2019, to fix this, manually remove **obj** and **bin** folders restart vs, and that's all :)